# What javascript/jquery tree view plug-in is most used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

What javascript/jquery tree view plug-in is most used?
(["Treeview"](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) seems to come up often in searches.....)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, **[that](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/)** is the one you should/can go for. Although google has many more too for you to dig out.

Comment: @Tommy: Yup, it is a good bet :)

Answer (score 3):

I found jsTree http://www.jstree.com/ much more customizable and useful even in pre 1.0 versions.